# Adding new keys to a python dictionary from variables?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to add new key-key-value registers to a python dictionary where key and key will be taken as variable names in a loop, here is my code:

```
def harvestTrendingTopicTweets(twitterAPI, trendingTopics, n):
    statuses = {}
    for category in trendingTopics:
        for trend in trendingTopics[category]:
            results = twitterAPI.search.tweets(q=trend, count=n, lang='es')
        statuses[category][trend] = results['statuses']
    return statuses
```

`trendingTopics` is a dictionary generated after this json

```
{
    "General": ["EPN","Peña Nieto", "México","PresidenciaMX"],
    "Acciones politicas": ["Reforma Fiscal", "Reforma Energética"]
}
```

So far I'm getting `KeyError: u'Acciones politicas'` error message as such key doesn't exist. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices. Either use [`dict.setdefault`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
statuses.setdefault(category, {})[trend] = results['statuses']
```

`setdefault` checks for the key `category`, and if that doesn't exist, sets `statuses[category]` to the second argument, in this case a new `dict`. That is then returned from the function, so `[trend]` is operated on the dictionary inside `statuses`, be it the new one or one that existed

---

Or create a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
...
statuses = defaultdict(dict)
```

`defaultdict` is similar to a `dict`, but instead of raising `KeyError`s when a key isn't found, it calls the method passed as argument. In this case, `dict()` which creates a new `dict` instance at that key.

Comment: What would `dict` in `statuses = defaultdict(dict)` mean?

Answer (score 1):

Before you assign a value to the dictionary elements, you need to make sure that the key actually exists. So, you can do

```
statuses.setdefault(category, {})[trend] = results['statuses']
```

This makes sure that, if the `category` is not found, then the second parameter will be used as the default value. So, if the current `category` doesn't exist in the dictionary, a new dictionary will be created.